# High Power LED connected to Dry battery

Tags: led, driver, surface-mount

I am new to electronics as i love working with circuits. I have 12V 6W SMD LED, which I want to attach with Battery Powered Driver which currently gives me from 10v-14v DC with 50mAmp. Shall I connect that LED directly with battery or may I need some circuit like defined here http://www.instructables.com/id/Super-simple-high-power-LED-driver/?ALLSTEPS . pls note.. I am not student.

Comment: never connect leds without anything that limits the current

Comment: You say you have a "Battery Powered Driver". What is that?

Comment: Well driver is which provide regulated voltage and current to to LED. I have a charger with 12V battery. WHich is originaly made for CCTV Camera Backup Supply. I want to use that for lighting up those high power LED at different dark spots at my home.

Comment: @PlasmaHH how can I limit current. How should I know the resistance required to secure LED

Comment: @AsifEjaz: by looking at the leds datahseet.

Comment: thanks @PlasmaHH . will you tell me why on earth LM317 Regulator is used?

Comment: @AsifEjaz: ask whoever used one, I can not mind read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must understand that your question is incomplete without some specifications of your "12V 6W SMD LED".

Having said that, since no real straightforward LED (light emitting diode) device works with a forward voltage of 12V, I suspect what you have there is really a "LED bulb" made of several real LEDs, and containing some internal voltage regulation circuitry.

If this is really the case, and without any information about your device, I believe you could probably hook it up to your 10-14VDC source with no problem.

Comment: http://www.evselectro.com/lights/high-power-lights/12v-6w-12-smd-high-power-led-6520 thats what I have

Comment: This is not a specification of the device. What you need is some figures, specifically the typical forward voltage and driving current.

Comment: Also, it seems from the picture that there is no voltage regulation circuitry, so you might need some external regulation, depending on the device's figures and your power source

Comment: well I think i should consult some electronics engineer then. Because I dont have those figures. I just showed what i Have.

Comment: i believe it doenst have any internal voltage regulation. because its way cheaper

Comment: Whoever you bought the device from should be able to provide you with its specifications.

Comment: I asked, they dont have such information. its only 12V 6W SMD LED.